# nested loop in python with lists input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to have an array of signals which calculated from a function, by loop through different parameter combination, something like below:

```
fast_w = list(range(20, 100, 20))
slow_w = list(range(100, 200, 20))
tradeSignal = np.zeros((len(fast_w), len(slow_w)))
for i in fast_w:
    for j in slow_w:
        tradeSignal[i][j] = signalTrade(i, j, stock_price, end_date)
```

however "tradeSignal[i][j]" is incorrect as i and j would be the values in the fast_w and slow_w list, which here it suppose to be the index of array  tradeSignal

So what is the right way to write such code?
new to python and its package ....thanks for help

Comment: What does your function signalTrade do?

Comment: Have you been printing step by step of your code? Like, if you print fast_w, your output is : [20, 40, 60, 80], is this your desired output at this point? You said "tradeSignal[i][j]" is incorrect, you must find out when you start to get unwanted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I'm not certain that it works, since we're missing part of your code, but it should.

```py
trade_signal = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: signalTrade(i, j, stock_price, end_date), shape=(4, 5))
```

When working with numpy, you should avoid explicit loops and iteration unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: hmmmm....why is that so? avoiding explicit loops and iteration?

Comment: It defeats the purpose of using numpy in the first place! The people who work on numpy already wrote all the loops for you, so that you can use more abstract and high-level function. Rewriting the loops yourself makes your code far more verbose than it needs to be, on top of increasing the risk of making a mistake. It also kills performance, when compared to numpy's functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use builtin function `enumerate()`.

`enumerate(iterable)` will let you iterate getting tuples `(index, value_from_iterable)`.

For example:

```py
for idx, x in enumerate(range(5, 8)):
    print(idx, x)
```

This code will produce the nex result:

```
0 5
1 6
2 7
```

Hence, your code will look like this:

```py
fast_w = list(range(20, 100, 20))
slow_w = list(range(100, 200, 20))
tradeSignal = np.zeros((len(fast_w), len(slow_w)))
for i, fast_val in enumerate(fast_w):
    for j, slow_val in enumerate(slow_w):
        tradeSignal[i][j] = signalTrade(fast_val, slow_val, stock_price, end_date)
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

Comment: hmm...that helps! but after I do that, got a new error saying: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @EstherLi are you sure that ```signalTrade``` returns you a single value? It looks like it doesn't.

Comment: oh, yes! you are right, it is not a single value but it is a Dataframe......the question becomes what should do now? should I set a dic upfront?

Comment: You can always change ```np.zeros((len(fast_w), len(slow_w)))``` to ```np.array((len(fast_w), len(slow_w)), dtype=numpy.object)```. This way ```tradeSignal``` will become array with objects of the custom type.

Comment: I solved it in another way to avoid to put Dataframe into an array. Thanks!